# Running Function in a loop using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've this js to hide and show elements. But I want to run this function 10 times with different function names. The function is supposed to perform same task each time by displaying 10 different div elements.

```
function onOffFunction5() {
    var x = document.getElementById("onOff5");
    if (x.style.display == "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("onOff5").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

To hide/show 10 different div elements I'm running this function 10 times with different names like onOffFfunction1, onOffFfunction2.... and so on. Help needed!

Comment: Just pass the identifier of the element in as an argument and call the function in a loop.

Comment: This line `x.style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("onOff5").style.display = 'none';` is not making any sense to me.